# JavaScript - Read Json if first value if is Zero

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a Json file like this

```
{
"0":{
    "poperty1":"poperty1",
    "poperty2":"poperty2",
    },
"1":{
    "poperty1":"poperty1",
    "poperty2":"poperty2",
    },
"2":{
    "poperty1":"poperty1",
    "poperty2":"poperty2",
    },
}
```

And i read it with this function:

```
function readJson(){
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", "file.json", false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0)
        {
            // console.log(JSON.parse(rawFile.responseText));
        }
    }
};
rawFile.send(null);
return JSON.parse(rawFile.responseText);
}
```

But it return every value exept the 0

```
"1":{
    "poperty1":"poperty1",
    "poperty2":"poperty2",
    },
"2":{
    "poperty1":"poperty1",
    "poperty2":"poperty2",
    }
```

even if i removit and start the json with 1 it return the 1 as well.

so any idea why?

Comment: There is no `0` value in the JSON you posted. Please [edit] your question and include the _actual_ results. Also log the result without the JSON parsing.

Comment: Also you have to wait for the request to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

I updated [your JSON](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crisz/file/master/file.json) on github, and I tested both the XHR response and the parsed object, in order to check that is correct, and I can say for sure it works properly:

```js
function readJson(){
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crisz/file/master/file.json", false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0)
        {
            console.log(JSON.parse(rawFile.responseText));
        }
    }
};
rawFile.send(null);
// return JSON.parse(rawFile.responseText);
}

readJson();
```

In the previous answer I hadn't notice the return inside the asynchronous function, if you have doubts about how asynchronous functions work in Javascript, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323).

#### Old answer

Your JSON is malformed. The [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) doesn't expect a comma at the end of the last key-value of a set.

Remove the trailing commas, and the parsing will work:

```
{
"0":{
    "poperty1":"poperty1",
    "poperty2":"poperty2"
    },
"1":{
    "poperty1":"poperty1",
    "poperty2":"poperty2"
    },
"2":{
    "poperty1":"poperty1",
    "poperty2":"poperty2"
    }
}
```

If also removing commas you have still problems in the resulting object, then try testing your API endpoint to see if the response is what you expect.

Comment: I see it.
But in my code i have more objets, i remove some to not make the question to long. So my "real" Json is a valid one.